# Lost photos in Shotwell after upgrade

Tags: shotwell

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu to 14.04 LTS from the previous 12.04. Unfortunately for me, I can't seem to find all my photos including documents that I had with the new version. I remember when upgrading to have answered to keep all documents and photos. Is there a way for me to retrieve these or they are gone.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the images may still be around, just not in a directory you know.

I assume it's a larger amount of data? You could look at the disk usage of directories to find them. For example with `baobab` or `filelight`, `ncdu` in a terminal.

Also, if you know parts of filenames, use `locate`:

```
locate -i '*foo*'
```

`locate` uses an index; it's very fast, but what it finds depends on configuration, and may be outdated.

Next to try is `find`, looking on every file name on the system - which will take a while:

```
find / -type f -iname '*foo*'
```